# how to get specific values from curl response in php

Tags: javascript, php, curl

I have the following format of response from using curl:

```
{
    "result": {
        "total": 1,
        "userquery": "my own query",
        "items": [
            {
                "coord": {
                    "a": -326.9159528,
                    "b": 12.0192037
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to save the parts after "a": and "b": so only the two sets of number will be saved in php variables.

How can I do it? And what would be the best way of doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data you have received is JSON. You will need to decode the data using [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode) and then access the variables:

```
$data = json_decode($curl_response);

$a = $data->result->items[0]->coord->a;
$b = $data->result->items[0]->coord->b;
```

[**Example/Demo**](http://www.tehplayground.com/#OAyS0MXTj)